# Eclipse plugin: how to modify the tab context menu

Tags: eclipse-rcp, contextmenu, eclipse-3.6

When developing Eclipse RCP application, on the view part, right click on the tab, you can see a context menu with "detached, restore, move, size, minimize, maximize" actions. I was wondering how to add a new action to that tab context menu? What's the correct keyword for this?

Most of results I found is about the general context menu, which is the one you get when right click anywhere in the viewpart. Where what I am looking for is the context menu from the tab.

Or what I should do is set some properties which make the context menu only showing when right click on the tab area.

What I am trying to do is add an option "Duplicate Tab" to context menu.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Eclipse 3.x as those context menu items don't exist on Eclipse 4.x. I am not sure this menu can be changed on 3.x

Comment: Yep, I am using Eclipse 3.6

Comment: Any solution ? I have similar problem. I want to localize this context menu when the program language is changed. How can I localize this menu ?